# How to use the value of this in custom jquery function to make the function output the data

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this custom function i am writing:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.createGallery = function(options) {
        //alert(this);
        console.log(this);
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            server: 'http://localhost/jQuery%20Gallery/images/galleries/',
            galleryName: 'Test',
            galleryWidth: 800,
            galleryImageMargin: 20,
            galleryImageColumns: 2,
            galleryTargetFolder: 'homepage_gallery',
            imageQuality: 100
        }, options);

        var galleryImageWidth = settings.galleryWidth / settings.galleryImageColumns;
        var imageUrl = settings.server+settings.galleryTargetFolder;

        var otherMargin = Math.round(settings.galleryImageMargin / 2);
        var finalImageWidth = Math.round(galleryImageWidth - settings.galleryImageMargin);
        var finalImageHeight = Math.round(galleryImageWidth / 1.4);
        var finalGalleryWidth = settings.galleryWidth - settings.galleryImageMargin;

        $(this).before('<style>'+this+' li:nth-child('+settings.galleryImageColumns+'n+1) { margin-left: 0; } '+this+' li:first-child { margin-left: 0; } '+this+' { width: '+finalGalleryWidth+'px; margin: 0px; } '+this+' li { display: inline-block; list-style: none; margin-left: '+settings.galleryImageMargin+'px; margin-bottom: '+otherMargin+'px; } </style>');

        $.ajax({
            url: imageUrl,
            success: function(data){
                $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
                    // will loop through 
                    var filename = $(this).attr("href");
                    $('<li></li>').html('<img src="thumbnail.php?src='+imageUrl+'/'+filename+'&q='+imageQuality+'&h='+finalImageHeight+'&w='+finalImageWidth+'"/>').appendTo(this);
                });
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Which is called using the following line:

```
$('#images').createGallery({
    server: 'http://localhost/jQuery%20Gallery/images/galleries/',
    galleryName: 'Test',
    galleryWidth: 800,
    galleryImageMargin: 20,
    galleryImageColumns: 2,
    galleryTargetFolder: 'homepage_gallery',
    imageQuality: 100
});
```

`console.log(this)` returns `ul#images`. As you can see in my code i have tried calling `this` to reflect the id that has been found. However, in the code it returns as `[object Object]`. How can i use `this` to reflect the object i am applying my function to?

Comment: Do you mean when you are creating your css? If so use `this.id`

Comment: Yes @Anton but also when appending the li's into the ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).selector` instead of "this".
"selector" is a property of jQuery-Objects with returns the selector in String-format.

Thus your line:

```
$(this).before('<style>'+this+' li:nth-child [...]
```

Should become:

```
$(this).before('<style>'+$(this).selector+' li:nth-child [...]
```

Comment: $('<li></li>').html('<img src="thumbnail.php?src='+imageUrl+'/'+filename+'&q='+imageQuality+'&h='+finalImageHeight+'&w='+finalImageWidth+'"/>').appendTo(this);

How do i get this line to work, i need it to append to the selector

Comment: [...].appentTo($(this)); should do the trick, as you can use the jQuery-object here again. Within the selector you need the String provided my Object.selector. For Object.appendTo you need to pass an Object, thus "$(this)" is sufficient.

Comment: My script is now outputting nothing, but i think its my own code error. I shall take a look and let you know what the error might be

Comment: Found it, i cannot use $(this) in the appendTo as $(this) is something different inside the ajax call. What should i use instead?

Comment: Assign $(this) to a variable before the ajax call and pass that variable into the appendTo()

Comment: To attempt to clarify things for you: In jQuery, the element being acted upon is often passed to the function parameter of a jQuery function as "this" [Source (properly put into this short sentence)](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?42053-jQuery-%28this%29-usage). It can be made into a jQuery element object by using "$(this)" in the function parameter. "$(this)" is an object, thus you couldn't use it within a selector. Selectors only accept Strings though, thus we had to use the "selector" property of "$(this)"

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).attr("id")` instead (which you should cache with your other values.) In your function, `this` refers to the HTML element.

Comment: This works great. But how do i fix the line of $('<li></li>').html('<img src="thumbnail.php?src='+imageUrl+'/'+filename+'&q='+imageQuality+'&h='+finalImageHeight+'&w='+finalImageWidth+'"/>').appendTo(this); to append to ul id of images?

Comment: Within the scope of your `createGallery` function, you should save the reference to the `ul` like so: `var self = $(this);` - then, use that where you were using `this` before. It will work in the line where you create the `style` tag, as well as in the `success` function. The reason is that function has access to the variables in the surrounding function (`createGallery`).